# Is there a function like auto.arima which gives the best VAR model according to a metric like AIC?

Tags: r, forecasting, model-selection, aic, vector-autoregression

The function `auto.arima` from the [forecast](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.20/topics/auto.arima) package, automatically fits the best **ARIMA** model given a time series, by evaluating on a metric like AIC, AICc or BIC.

I am looking for a similar function which does the same, but fits a **VAR (Vector Auto Regression)** model to a bunch of time series variables. Is there any such function in any package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A close one is [`VARselect`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vars/versions/1.5-6/topics/VARselect) from the `vars` package. It returns optimal lag orders according four information criteria (AIC, BIC a.k.a. SC, FPE and HQ). Then you can manually specify the selected lag order and estimate the model with `VAR` as follows:

```r
aic <- VARselect(Canada, lag.max=5, type="const")$selection["AIC(n)"]
model <- VAR(Canada, p=aic, type="const")
print(model)
```